# Azure Signature Special Character

Tags: azure, special-characters, azure-blob-storage, signature

I got a little infrequently problem with user uploads and azure blob storage.
Sometimes the names of the files containing special character like this little one ø. So if I'm generating an access signature with an rscd parameter for renaming the file concerning download the signature is different from the url parameter and I'm getting the following error from azure:

```
403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
```

Here's an example of a url which causes the problem

```
<storageurl>/YjplCzqEf6kSdCyhJtPiVahZRxZpEKGENSQkWjQL/xJC6Z3fFs7MnhDbNrmrQ7nflzoX8Rk9eUBbJtgeM/eQ1mk31DfijdwpoUEcTmmSr7jtHEALhFs8RE1J77.mp3?se=2015-11-11T08%3A09%3A36Z&sr=b&sp=r&sv=2014-02-14&rscd=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22Crazy+For+You+%28Feat.+Bish%C3%B8p%29+-+Zonderling.mp3%22
```

You can see that the original file name containing the word "Bishøp".

What would be the best solution to avoid getting problems because of the special chars?

Comment: Hi, can you provide a little more detail about your case? If you could include the SAS URL (without the signature), that would be helpful. 

It sounds like the special character is in the blob name, is that correct? Are you escaping the special character per the instructions at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135715.aspx?

Comment: Hi, I just added an example url. The special char isn't in the blobs' name but I want to force a renaming when the user downloads the file and the original file name contains special chars.

Comment: I just tried making a service call with the following url and didn't encounter any issues. Can you provide any more information here that would could help us repro your issue?
/utcontainerd9160cf4/Bish%C3%B8p?sp=r&sr=b&rscd=attachment%3B%20filename%3DBish%C3%B8p&sig=...&se=2015-12-12T19%3A31%3A44Z&sv=2015-04-05